# finding punctuations except for - regex

Tags: java, regex

so I was trying to get rid of words that have punctuations except for -.I was trying to use .match() from string and delete the whole string if it's false. I tried

```
public static void removeWords(String [] array){
    int i;
    boolean isWords;

    for(i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
        isWords = checkWord(array[i]);
        if (isWords == false)
            array[i] = "";
    }

}

public static boolean checkWord(String word){
    if (word.matches("[a-zA-Z[\\-]]")){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

but it won't recognize -.

edit:
so "he789llo" should be deleted but "he-llo" shouldn't be.but both words were being deleted by that code

Comment: Show us the input that you are using, along with the expected result, and whatever result that you are getting now. It will be easier to see what you are doing wrongly.

Comment: you don't need [-], but you can escape it with `\-`

Comment: Please post full code. `[a-zA-Z[-]]` matches 1 character that is either `a-z` or `A-Z` or `-`. Niote that in Java unescaped square brackets inside a character class are ignored. Perhaps, you are looking for `+` quantifier to match 1 or more characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put `-` within another character class also you need to put a `+` or `*` after your character class :

```
[a-zA-Z-]+
```